# Is it possible to import DV video using Firewire?

Tags: video, hardware, video-editor

I know there are several video editing programs: PiTiVi, Openshot, etc

However I am unsure if I can transfer video footage from a DV tape to my computer. In other operating systems (with the correct software) I can connect my firewire camcorder or tape deck to a pc, and record the video to file in realtime.

Is this possible in Ubuntu and if so which software is needed?

Comment: Preferably a GTK application, or possibly a CLI app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use the command line program `dvgrab` to pull from my minidv camcorder over firewire.

The command I use is:

```
sudo dvgrab -a -format raw -rewind -t prefix-
```

The permissions are messed up, which is why you need sudo. Afterwards, just do:

```
sudo chown username:username prefix-*.dv
```

The rewind command rewinds the tape, so leave it off if you don't want to rewind.

The prefix- gets appended to the file name to help you identify it. The files are automatically split when dvgrab finds a time gap or every 2GB.

[Manpage for the `dvgrab` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/dvgrab) has a few more useful options.

Comment: Thank you brousch. You made my old Sony DCR-HC24E live again in Ubuntu 12.04. Only added -srt to the command:
'sudo dvgrab -srt -a -format raw -rewind -t prefix-'

Comment: replace "prefix-" with the prefix you want to chose.

Answer (score 1):

In short, [it's possible](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Firewire) but thanks to regression upon regression, it's a pain in the rear.

In Lucid it involves telling udev to keep its paws off the firewire device and let it be a raw interface:

```
echo 'KERNEL=="raw1394", GROUP="video", MODE="0664"' |
sudo tee /etc/udev/rules.d/50-raw1394.rules
&& sudo restart udev
```

You then plug you camera in, hit play on the camera then use something like kino that interfaces with the dvgrab package to record the video to disk. As I mentioned: PITA.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Firewire